# asp.net and ms access how to get data based on a joint field

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

I have two MS access tables in my asp.net application (named `categories` & `books`) . The first table (`Categories`) has two fields named `Category_ID` and `Category_Name`.

The second table has three fields named `Book_ID`, `Category_ID` and `Bookname` (category_id is joint field in two tables. In some Pages I have the `category_name` and I want to get book rows with that `category` name. In other words I should first get the `category id` based on `category name` that i have then select from books where the categoryID matchs.  But I don't know how.

thank you

Comment: Have a look at [Joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb243855(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Book.* FROM 
Book INNER JOIN Category ON Book.Category_ID = Category.Category_ID
WHERE Category.category_name = 'TheName'
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd use a join, something like:

```
select books.Bookname
,categories.Category_Name
from books
inner join categories on categories.Category_ID = books.Category_ID
where categories.Category_Name = 'your-category'
```